# Calculated table circular dependency issue

Tags: dax, ssas, data-modeling

I am building a datamodel in Analysis Services, in which there are four tables. Table1, Table2 and Table3 are tables that are loaded from a database. Table4 is a calculated table, made from Table2 and Table3 through the union function.

Table1 and Table2 have a relationship.

Table1 and Table3 also have a relationship.

When I try to make a relationship between Table1 and Table4, I get a circular dependency error. Several of the calculations in Table2 use the relationship to Table1.

Is it impossible to have a relationship to a calculated table, when its 'parent' table already has a relationship to the same table?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It is most likely that the calculations in Table2 (that are using the relationship to Table1) is causing the circular dependency. Update your question with a little more detail like the CD error message, dax of the calculations, etc...

Comment: Further to the above comment, if you are using `ALL` then try replacing it to `ALLNOBLANKROW`, likewise with `VALUES`, replace with `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Make the same table in PowerQuery instead.

Comment: @SamNseir The model is rather complicated, with a lot of calculated columns, dependencies, and so on, so it would take too long to cover all of it. But it seems ALLNOBLANKROW worked with the union function, so that I could make a relationship between Table1 and Table4. So thank you!

On a side note, the better approach would probably be to root out the circular dependencies, which would require redesigning the model. Only, I don't have time to do that now.